# Page anchor getting stripped from url

Tags: marketing-cloud, web-analytics-connector

Our website uses page anchors to filter by location and sort by price, etc. So if we want to link directly to a particular product category but have it filtered by location and sorted by most popular, we would use a link that looks like this:

```
https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com.au/racing/#location=qld;sortby=most+popular;
```

When we send an email that uses this link (copied as is into the link section of an image, not using redirectto() or any functions) the "#" onwards gets stripped out. Our WAC parameters are then added after this. So the resulting link looks like this:

```
https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com.au/racing/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=campaignname
```

I'm not sure if this is being caused by the WAC functionality or MC just strips out page anchors regardless?

Has anyone come across this and is there a solution to keep the page anchor string in the url and also keep the WAC parameters?

Thanks

Comment: It's not so much that you have a bookmark. WAC normally appends the bookmark to the end of your URL. It's to do with the way that your bookmark resembles a query string, I think. You'll see this if you URLEncode your bookmark  "https://www.xxx.com.au/racing/#location%3Dqld%3Bsortby%3Dmost%2Bpopular%3B". The bookmark's retained. I can't see a neat solution, without modifying your site's behaviour to have it accept query strings/URLEncoded bookmarks or go through something like a CloudPage to rewrite the URL and redirect to the destination incorporating this somewhat complex bookmark style.

Answer (score 0):

Finally had an answer from MC support and they say that if using WAC functionality, then page anchors will get stripped from links and that this is functioning correctly.

So seems it's not possible.